# HIDE /SHOW Menu Names in Blazor

Tags: c#, user-interface, blazor-webassembly

I am New to Blazor UI development I have been trying to work on this menu to initially look like in this picture

[image: Before Button event]

after a button click on the top of the menu it should look like the below picture
[image: after a button click on the top of the menu it should look like the below picture]

the code I tried was hiding the menu with icons too , Kindly Help me out here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use another library (extension) on top of Blazor. A very handy and proven (free to use) library is, for example, MudBlazor. You can find the documentation here: https://mudblazor.com/

What you describe can be achieved using this library, for example with the following code:

```
<MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@ToggleDrawer" />

<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Mini">
    <MudNavMenu >
        <MudNavLink Icon="@Icons.Filled.Calculate">Link1</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Icon="@Icons.Filled.LocalCafe">Link2</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavMenu>
</MudDrawer>

@code {
    private bool open = true;

    private void ToggleDrawer()
    {
        open = !open;
    }
}
```

You can try this code here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaQmYZEsxBSUEJuv

Comment: this works great Thanks,  but cant i do it with Using HTML and bootstrap css  please help on this .

Answer (score 0):

I dont know will it work for you but u can try something like making 2 panel one is for logos and other is for texts. Then just write `panel2.visible = false` in form load. After that write inside that showing texts button.

```
if (panel2.visibile == false)
{
    panel2.visible = true
}
    else if (panel2.visibile == true)
{
    panel2.visible = false
}
```

I dont know is this what u want but u can try it just 3 lines of code